# ¿Cuál es la ventaja de usar Lambdas y Method References?

Tags: java, lambda

He estado tomando un curso de Java, han tocado estos temas.
Probablemente porque no estoy tan familiarizada me parecen confusos y no los veo como algo necesario, así que quisiera saber ¿cuál es la ventaja de usarlos?
¿En que casos consideran que se necesitan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tengo muy claro por qué te han votado negativo a la pregunta. Ya que me parece una pregunta totalmente válida.

Pongamos que tenemos una función que recorre una lista de números y los suma.
Pongamos que tenemos otra función que los multiplica. Y una última que los resta.

Todo esto se puede resolver con funciones standard del lenguaje. Pero son ejemplos simples, luego podemos ir a cosas mas complicadas.

Si no usamos lambdas ni otros métodos el código sería algo así:

```
    val numbers = listOf(1,2,3,4,5)

    var acc = 0

    for (number in numbers) {
        acc += number
    }

    var accMultiplication = 0

    for (number in numbers) {
        accMultiplication *= number
    }

    var accRest = 0

    for (number in numbers) {
        accRest -= number
    }
```

E inmediatamente vemos un patrón. Siempre iteramos sobre la lista y la reducimos a un único número, lo único que cambia es la operación.

Si queremos hacer un método único para todas las operaciones, deberíamos conocer dichas operaciones... lo cual es imposible.

Como soportaríamos el caso en el que por cada número tenemos que consultar a un servicio y sumarlo solo si ese servicio dice que sí, por ejemplo?

Por ello, y otros motivos, se opta por permitir introducir la función que se va a ejecutar para cada elemento.

Y cómo hacemos eso? pues con lambdas o method reference.
La diferencia entre usar uno y otro es que muchas veces el método solo se usa una vez y es mas claro tenerlo in-line que referenciar a otro método.

Siguiendo esa idea podríamos crear una función que se encargue de reducir una lista de números a un único número:

```
    fun Iterable<Int>.fold(initial: Int, operation: (acc: Int, Int) -> Int): Int {
        var accumulator = initial
        for (element in this) accumulator = operation(accumulator, element)
        return accumulator
    }
```

Y la podemos usar de esta forma en los ejemplos anteriores:

```
    val acc = numbers.fold(0) { accumulator, number ->
        accumulator + number
    }

    val accMultiplication = numbers.fold(0) { accumulator, number ->
        accumulator * number
    }

    val accRest = numbers.fold(0) { accumulator, number ->
        accumulator - number
    }
```

Pero qué diferencia hay en hacer esto y no un for cuando es necesario?
La verdad es que en esta etapa, poca.

Pero también podemos pensar qué diferencia hay entre hace un for y usar Math.sum?

Este tipo de funciones cobran mucha fuerza cuando usamos tipos generalizados.
si cambiamos nuestro función a la siguiente:

```
public inline fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.fold(initial: R, operation: (acc: R, T) -> R): R {
    var accumulator = initial
    for (element in this) accumulator = operation(accumulator, element)
    return accumulator
}
```

En este caso estamos usando tipos genéricos. Así que aceptamos un valor inicial que puede ser de cualquier tipo. Y una lista que también puede ser de cualquier tipo. Y la única restricción es que el valor final es del mismo tipo que el inicial.

Para nuestros ejemplos podemos seguir utilizando la función de la misma forma.
Pero podemos hacer más cosas. Por ejemplo, concatenar todos los números como un string

```
val numbersString = numbers.fold(0) { accumulator, number -> "$accumulator-$number" }
```

Y me reitero. Todo esto es muy fácil de hacer con funciones del lenguaje. Así que veamos ejemplos más reales o complejos.

Ejemplo 1: Dados dos futuros, cuando ambos han acabado convertirlos a otro tipo de objeto y retornar un nuevo futuro con ese valor

```
    return resultOneFuture.thenCombine(resultTwoFuture) { resultOneResult, resultTwoResult ->
        otherService.createSpecificObject(resultOneResult, resultTwoResult)
    }
```

Ejemplo 2: Dado una lista de objetos transformarla a otro tipo de objetos

```
metrics.filterNot { it.hidden }.map { NewObjectType(it.name, it.title, it.unit) }
```

Ejemplo 3: Dada una lista de objetos separarlos en 2 listas en base a una condición

```
httpCalls.partition { it.isSuccess }
```

Si intentas escribir el mismo código usando for's while o lo que quieras. Casi siempre acabarás con más código que el mostrado aqui.
Muchas otras veces es mucho mas claro ver un método con un nombre claro que no ver un for e intentar adivinar que está pasando.

Por otro lado, todas estas funciones son de Kotlin. He usado Kotlin concretamente porque tiene muchas funciones de este tipo. Y si miras el código verás muy claro que internamente son un for.

Por ejemplo este es el código para `partition`

```
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.partition(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Pair<List<T>, List<T>> {
    val first = ArrayList<T>()
    val second = ArrayList<T>()
    for (element in this) {
        if (predicate(element)) {
            first.add(element)
        } else {
            second.add(element)
        }
    }
    return Pair(first, second)
}
```

No hay magia en ningún sitio. Simplemente es mas legible y se puede reutilizar mucho mejor por todo el código